# angular - How can jQuery inside a custom directive respond to a $scope change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can jQuery in a custom directive respond to a $scope change?

```
<div id="wrapper" scrolldirective>          
  <div id="scroller">Hello this is a test<div>
</div>
```

note: $timeout is only inside the directive to push .scrollTop() to the end of the update cycle as per this thread [Angular & jQuery:horizontal scrolling a div from a controller or directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175761/angular-jqueryhorizontal-scrolling-a-div-from-a-controller-or-directive)

```
myapp.directive('scrolldirective', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $(element).scrollTop( scope.mytop );
      }, 1);
    }
  };
});
```

and finally some $scope code that I want the directive to react to

```
$scope.mytop = 500;  
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.setPosition(50);
},1000);
$scope.setPosition = function(arg){
  $log.log('===> ',arg);
  $scope.mytop = arg;
  $scope.$apply();  // ???
}
```

edit:

here is a jsFiddle with all the minimal code to get this running.  Unfortunately jsFiddle's UI adds its own scrollbars to the panels which interferes with this!  Grr. But at leas all the code is there if you feel like copying it out.  http://jsfiddle.net/PrimeLens/CV5L8/

Comment: `$timeout` call `$apply` - no need to include `$apply` in a function called within `$timout`

Comment: You'll have to `scope.$watch` in your directive for the value of `scope.mytop` changing. Either that, or broadcast an event from your controller, that your directive will listen for.

Comment: @Ian which is the better way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't hear back from Ian (see comments) but what he said led me to the solution. 
I've posted a working set of code here https://github.com/PrimeLens/angular-MVP-custom-directive-jquery-with-data-binding

```
scope.$watch('variableName', function() {
    // 
});
```